# How to replace quotation marks in a JSON file with \" in bash?

Tags: json, regex, linux, bash, sed

For example, there is a string value read from a line of file.

```
{"ip":"91.239.165.20","timestamp":"2015-10-16T14:14:31-04:00","data":{"banner":"220 ********.****rn","ehlo":"502 Error: command "EHLO" not implementedrn","starttls":"502 Error: command "STARTTLS" not implementedrn"},"error":"Bad return code for STARTTLS","error_component":"starttls"}
```

As you can see there is a phrase "EHLO" was included in a string, it is like

`"something "EHLO"   the end"`

But now I want to make this line looks like this,

```
"something \\"EHLO\\"   the end"
```

How to transform replace quotation marks in this line of JSON data?

In bash, regex or whatever...

It should be run in command line.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is a bug in the program that produced the data which is both important and simple to fix. Which program is it?

Comment: Yup. As confirmed by http://jsonlint.com/ - that is invalid JSON, those quote marks need escaping by the provider.

Comment: Find and fix the broken program creating this output. Or find a less broken program to generate the output for you instead.

Comment: The data I got looked just like that. I have to re-collect this data. I don't have the program yet. Before accessing the program, I think it will keep on generating invalid JSON... But this has to be solved for now..

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for the 4th arg to split(), this will work with lines formatted as you've shown:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    n = split($0,f,/{"|"}|":{?"|"}?,"/,s)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        gsub(/"/,"\\\"",f[i])
        printf "%s%s", f[i], (i<n ? s[i] : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
{"ip":"91.239.165.20","timestamp":"2015-10-16T14:14:31-04:00","data":{"banner":"220 ********.****rn","ehlo":"502 Error: command \"EHLO\" not implementedrn","starttls":"502 Error: command \"STARTTLS\" not implementedrn"},"error":"Bad return code for STARTTLS","error_component":"starttls"}
```

If you have other formats that this doesn't work with then you should edit your question to make sure the sample input/output you provide is more truly representative of your real data.